# Multiple dropdown ( select2 select ) in React does not completely render when selected value is fetched from an external server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-select2

I am trying to update a form with data from an external database. I am using React.  All the components are working fine except for the dropdown selectBox.

I set the value field in the selectBox component to point to the state variable which gets updated ( using this.setState ().. ) when data is fetched.

However in the UI, I see that even though this data is highlighted in the dropdown list, it is not shown in the Selected columns on top of the selectBox ( small boxes with a cross at the end ). I even tried to force rerender with this.forceUpdate () but that did not help.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to use defaultValue instead of value ?

Comment: My defaultValue was set to null. Initially I want the values to be null and the data is fetched only on a trigger (button click).

Comment: Can you please share some code?